# Toplink without application server

Tags: java, database, toplink

Is it possible to use **Toplink Essentials** without application server, just on desktop application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes but for certain behaviour you may have to use the JVM startup options to enable the toplink agent. I believe this is for the lazy loading or something similar.

Do you mean TopLink or TopLink Essentials?  The first is a commercial Oracle product. The latter is the reference implementation of JPA 1.0, which is a somewhat cut down version.

Honestly I don't think there's any reason to use anything other than EclipseLink (which will be the JPA 2.0 reference implementation) or Hibernate.

To actually do this:

- [Hibernate for Java SE](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/11/16/hibernate-for-java-se.html);
- [Eclipselink in J2SE RCP Applications](http://www.weheartcode.com/2008/08/27/eclipselink-in-j2se-rcp-applications/); and
- [Using the Java Persistence API in Desktop Applications](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/persistenceapi/).

Comment: +1 for fast thinking and typing.  Pretty quick for this early on a Saturday.  8)

Comment: Its not Saturday morning everywhere. :)

Comment: I ment TopLink Essentials, but I'll take your recommendation and try EclipseLink and Hibernate :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, as long as you don't need JNDI naming services.  Toplink and Hibernate can both run without an app server.  You just need a relational database and a JDBC driver.

Answer (score 0):

yes, toplink is a pure Java class library